# LDAP PHP data from group

Tags: php, ldap

I'm new to using LDAP, so maybe I'm just not looking for the right thing or this isn't possible.

I am working in an Active Directory where there are students in groups which are their classes. Now I need the e-mail adresses from all the students from a certain class. I do have a connection to the Active Directory through LDAP, but because I literally have no idea how to approach this I don't have any code to show.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Active Directory, you'll have to bind using a service account before you can search the directory. After successful binding you can retrieve the e-mail addresses of all users in a group named "ICS-1" like this:

```
// $conn = ldap_connect()
// ldap_bind()
$basedn = "dc=rug,dc=nl"
$classname = "ICS-1"
$filter = "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=" . $classname ."))"
$search = ldap_search($conn, $basedn, $filter, array("dn"))
$groupdn = $search[0]["dn"]
$filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=" . $groupdn ."))"
$search = ldap_search($conn, $basedn, $filter, array("mail"))
```

`$basedn` is the naming context storing your groups and users.  Please, consult the [available documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php) for the correct syntax of the ldap_ functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify the `dn` of you class, something like this :

`cn=classname,ou=classes,dc=domain,dc=com`

When you have this information, the most efficient way to retrieve the mails is :

```
// retrieve the members of this group : 
$result = ldap_read ( $AD , "<dn of the class>" , (objectClass=*) , ["member"]);
// Get the entry
$entry = ldap_get_entries ( $AD ,$result );
/* The entry should be an array like this : 
$entry = [ 
   "count" => 1, 
   "0" => [
     "dn" => "<dn of the class>",
     "member" => [...]
   ]
]
*/
// After that you can iterate through the members to read each user entry
$mails = [];
for ($i=0; $i< $entry[0]["member"]["count"]; $i++) {
   $studentDN = $entry[0]["member"][$i];
   $r = ldap_read ( $AD , $studentDN , (objectClass=*) , ["mail"]);
   $e = ldap_get_entries ( $AD ,$r );
   // $e is structured similarly to the previous $entry so the mail is at : 
   $mails[] = $e[0]["mail"][0];
}
```

I do not know really well Active Directory, so you should double check the attributes names to match your needs, but overall, it is the fastest / most efficient way to loop through an LDAP directory when you know the DN of the group.

Because LDAP directories are optimised for fast reading it will be easier for the server to read each entry one by one to fetch an attribute than doing a search on all the users to a matching attribute and after that to fetch all the mails and returned everything in one go.